# Can we add help textf for Lightning:progressIndicator steps

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system, lightning-community

[image]

any help or alternative to add helptext in lightning:progress indicator bar would be helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

That component is named Path. Open Setup and type Path in the Search box and it will take you to where the Path is configured for each page. Click on the Path for the page you want to add "guidance" and an editor will open for you. You'll find more details on many of the features in [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=path_overview.htm&type=5)